# CCTV Loop Out Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics

I need one camera IN & TWO outputs to feed into 2 DVRs.Just a resistor divider ok ?
Like this? Camera Types are AHD & Analog.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKSqI4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: do you have the camera and the two DVRs? .... if you do, then just connect them and see for yourself

Comment: Yes I have the camera & two DVRs.It is working but I want to confirm is it ok or any impedance mismatch etc...???

Comment: try just connecting both DVR using a wye cable.

Comment: If I make a Y cable where to place the 39R resisters?

Comment: the worst that will happen, is that you will have very bad quality video

Comment: Hi all, I checked on workbench the quality is ok. But when I installed in real site condition with longer Cable lengths the quality was worse.Very blur.Any improvements?